# Dúvida - Combobox dependentes com ASP Clássico

Tags: asp, combobox, vbscript, selected-option

Tenho duas tabelas no SQL:
**Uma de grupos que possui duas colunas: id e grupo**

**Uma de produtos que possui três colunas: id, grupo e produto**

***Na tabela produtos, a coluna "grupo" equivale à coluna "id" da tabela grupos.***

Estou tentando fazer um formulário de inclusão em uma terceira tabela de entradas (colunas: grupo, produto e entrada).

**Neste formulário, existe um combobox em que o usuário selecionará o Grupo e, ao selecionar o Grupo, deverá aparecer, em um segundo combobox, apenas os Produtos relacionados a ele. (semelhante ao combobox estado/cidade).**

A página web está conectando direitinho no banco de dados, mas não estou conseguindo fazer os combobox dependentes.

Construí da seguinte maneira:

**Combo dos grupos:**

```
<%
SET RS_grupo = conexao.execute("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[nova_pd_grupos] ORDER BY grupo")

grupo1= RS_grupo("grupo")
idgrupo=RS_grupo("id")
grupo=request.querystring("grupo1")

%>

<select class="custom-select custom-select-sm" name="idgrupo" onChange="location.href('index.asp?idgrupo='+formulario.idgrupo.options[formulario.idgrupo.selectedIndex].value)">
                                <% while not RS_grupo.eof%>
                                <% if grupo <>"" then
                                   if grupo = grupo1 then
                                   response.write "<option value="&idgrupo&"&grupo1="&grupo1&" selected>"&grupo1&"</option>"
                                   elseif grupo <> grupo1 then
                                   response.write "<option value="&idgrupo&"&grupo1="&grupo1&">"&grupo1&"</option>"
                                   end if
                                   else 
                                   response.write "<option value="&idgrupo&"&grupo1="&grupo1&">"&grupo1&"</option>"
                                   end if

                                   RS_grupo.movenext
                                   wend
                                   RS_grupo.close


                                %>


                            </select>
```

**Combo dos produtos:**

```
<% if request.querystring("idgrupo") <> "" then %>
                                <select class="custom-select custom-select-sm" name="produto">
<%  SET RS_produto = conexao.execute("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[nova_pd_produtos] where grupo = "&request.querystring("idgrupo")&" order by produto asc;")
                                while not RS_produto.eof

                                   grupo = request.querystring("grupo")
                                   produto1 = RS_produto("produto")
                                %>
                                <option  value="<%=produto1%>,<%=grupo%>">
                                    <%=produto1%>
                                </option>

                                     <%
                                        RS_produto.movenext
                                        wend
                                        RS_produto.close
                                        %>
                                </select>
                                <% end if %>
```

No entanto, **na lista de grupos aparecem 13 opções, todas com o nome da primeira opção.**
E na lista de produtos não aparece nada.

Alguém pode me ajudar?
**ASP clássico (vbscript).**

Obrigada!

Comment: O option nunca vai mudar porque `grupo1` nunca muda. Coloque os `grupo1= RS_grupo("grupo")` e `idgrupo=RS_grupo("id")` no início do `while`.

Comment: Beleza, agora aparece a lista com os options do grupo, mas ainda não aparece o combobox com a lista dos produtos. Acho que tem algo errado na forma como está estruturado o evento onChange na hora de selecionar o grupo.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver? Tem algo errado na resposta? Por favor, dê um feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem dois problemas no código:

Coloque as variáveis vindas do banco no início do primeiro `while`, senão elas não serão alteradas e terão o mesmo valor dentro do laço:

```
<%
while not RS_grupo.eof
   grupo1= RS_grupo("grupo")
   idgrupo=RS_grupo("id")
   ...
%>
```

E o `onchange` está com sintaxe errada. O correto é:

```
onchange="location.href = 'index.asp?idgrupo='+this.value"
```

O `this.value` irá retornar o valor da `option` selecionada.

Comment: consegui resolver, mas utilizando ajax... o onchange ele não muda de jeito nenhum.

Comment: Legal! Com Ajax tb é outra forma de carregar os dados.